# Bootstrap django - nav dropdown issue

Tags: html, django

Hi this is my first django project. I am trying to implement base templating. Using django 3 and free sb admin 2 template. I am having an issue with nav dropdown, what i am missing ? I was also having issue with sidebar but fixed that with templatetags. 
Please check [my template attachment here.](https://github.com/vwaaala/stackoverflow/tree/master)

[This is what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auO8E.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main.html, there is a typo in your script src tag. In last two script tags, the spelling of reception is incorrect in src tag. 
Try this:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
<script src="{% static '/reception/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static '/reception/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static '/reception/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```